# Find subjects with scores lower than 50 and display subject name in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

A table displays the scores of students in various subjects in a class.
Some students score less than the pass mark in some core subjects.

Now, in each student's result sheet, I want to display that they re-sit in the subjects that they scored less than 50 (pass mark).

For example - A student's score in physics and chemistry is 45 and 49 respectively which is less than the pass mark for those subjects.
His result sheet should say "RECOMMENDED FOR RE-SIT IN PHYSICS AND CHEMISTRY"

This is my if statement

```
  <?php

if ($value->h_tot_score >= 90 && $value->h_tot_score <= 100) {
   $result = 'PROMOTED TO THE NEXT CLASS';
                                               
} elseif ($value->h_tot_score >= 45 && $value->h_tot_score <= 49.99) {
  $result= 'RECOMMENDED FOR RE-SIT IN ';

} elseif ($value->h_tot_score >= 40 && $value->h_tot_score <= 44.99) {
  $result= 'RECOMMENDED FOR RE-SIT IN ';

} elseif ($value->h_tot_score >= 0 && $value->h_tot_score <= 39.99) {
  $result= 'RECOMMENDED FOR RE-SIT IN ';
}
?>
```

This is my query for getting the subjects with scores less than 50

```
SELECT `subject_id` FROM `hscores_primary` WHERE `class_id` in (15,16,17) and `student_id=461` AND `h_tot_score` <= 49.99
```

The result is subject_id =79 and 34

How do I automatically display or echo the subject names in my if statement above?

Comment: what table are the class names kept?

Comment: The class names are in a table called 'classes'

Answer (score 1):

You could do a LEFT JOIN. Assuming the row that holds the subject name in `subjects` is called `subject_name`

```
SELECT h.subject_id, h.h_tot_score, s.subject_name 
FROM hscores_primary h 
LEFT JOIN subjects s
ON h.subject_id = s.id
WHERE h.class_id IN (15,16,17) 
AND h.student_id=461
```

and the php

```
<?php

if ($value->h_tot_score >= 90 && $value->h_tot_score <= 100) {
  $result = 'PROMOTED TO THE NEXT CLASS';
} elseif ($value->h_tot_score >= 45 && $value->h_tot_score <= 49.99) {
  $result= 'RECOMMENDED FOR RE-SIT IN ' . $value->subject_name;
} elseif ($value->h_tot_score >= 40 && $value->h_tot_score <= 44.99) {
  $result= 'RECOMMENDED FOR RE-SIT IN ' . $value->subject_name;
} elseif ($value->h_tot_score >= 0 && $value->h_tot_score <= 39.99) {
  $result= 'RECOMMENDED FOR RE-SIT IN ' . $value->subject_name;
}
?>
```

Comment: okay, but I don't understand why you are joining it with the classes table. I need the subject name

Comment: I am confused. Where - what table - is the subject name kept? I am thinking subject is a class like biology.

Comment: no, subject names are kept in the table 'subjects'.

Comment: Again, how do I echo it out in the view. I'm kinda new to all these

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry I had a couple typos in the first one

Comment: Ok, just revised again. If you don't have that last WHERE AND for h_tot_score, (and also return h_tot_score as one of the results) then you can build that PHP if statemetn block.

Comment: Thank you for responding. But still, a bit confused as to where and how to place the query. Am I to put your query in my model? and what should go into the controller before I echo it in my view

Comment: What version of codeigniter are you using?

Comment: CI_VERSION = '3.1.6'